# paginador con php

Tags: php, paginación

trabajo en un paginador en php que es el siguiente:

```
    function pag($ini, $limit_end, $total){

  $url = basename($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]);

  if (isset($_REQUEST['busqueda'])) {
      $busqueda = strtolower(e($_REQUEST['busqueda']));

      if (empty($busqueda)) {
      $busq = "";
    } else {
      $busq = '&busqueda='.$busqueda;
    }


    } else {
      $busq = "";
      //unset($_REQUEST['busqueda']);
    }

echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">';
echo '<ul class="pagination">';
/****************************************/
if(($ini - 1) == 0)
{
echo "<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".(1).$busq."'><b><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i>  Principio</b></a></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i>  Anterior</a></li>";
}
else
{
echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".(1).$busq."'><b><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i>  Principio</b></a></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".($ini-1).$busq."'><b><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i>  Anterior</b></a></li>";
}
/****************************************/

  for($k=max(1, min($ini-5,$total-10));
  $k < max(min(11,$total+1), min($ini+5,$total+1));
  $k++)
  {
if($ini == $k){
    echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
}
else{
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
}
}



/****************************************/
if($ini == $total)
{
echo "<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='#'>Siguiente <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i> </a></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".($total).$busq."'><b>Ultima <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i></b></a></li>";
}
else
{
echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".($ini+1).$busq."'><b>Siguiente <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i></b></a></li>";
echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".($total).$busq."'><b>Ultima <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i></b></a></li>";
}
/*******************END*******************/
echo "</ul>";
// echo "</div>";
echo '</nav>';
}
```

Implementandolo le ingreso los datos solicitados y funciona con una salvedad y es que si le doy click al boton buscar y no se envia ningun valor en el input entonces la web muestra `www.miweb.com?busqueda=` y me gustaria hacer la correccion a que si el input no posee nada escrito entonces la web que muestre el navegador sea `www.miweb.com` alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

no te puedo añadir un comentario, te lo pongo como respuesta.
Por lo que veo, tal como lo tienes es mas un tema de configuracion del fichero htacces.

Saludos! ;)

Te adjunto la solucion!
En tu htaccess pon:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?AQUI_PARAMETRO_QUE_VENDRA_POR_GET=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hola, lo siento antes no podia, ahora lo elimino y lo pongo donde toca! ;)

Comment: Solución agregada.;)